# Bokeh "server.start" not showing anything

Tags: python, bokeh

My code is meant to track flights all over the world, but whenever I try to run my program, nothing shows up on the page. I observed that after starting the server, the program stops. So, I used command prompt and put `bokeh serve flight.py`. This time it started, and kept running, but with a different port than declared and it still didn't show anything. Any help?

My Code (flight.py):

````
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import HoverTool,LabelSet,ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, STAMEN_TERRAIN
import numpy as np
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler

def wgs84_to_web_mercator(df, lon="long", lat="lat"):
    k = 6378137
    df["x"] = df[lon] * (k * np.pi/180.0)
    df["y"] = np.log(np.tan((90 + df[lat]) * np.pi/360.0)) * k
    return df

def wgs84_web_mercator_point(lon,lat):
    k = 6378137
    x= lon * (k * np.pi/180.0)
    y= np.log(np.tan((90 + lat) * np.pi/360.0)) * k
    return x,y

lon_min,lat_min=-125.974,30.038
lon_max,lat_max=-68.748,52.214

xy_min=wgs84_web_mercator_point(lon_min,lat_min)
xy_max=wgs84_web_mercator_point(lon_max,lat_max)

x_range,y_range=([xy_min[0],xy_max[0]], [xy_min[1],xy_max[1]])

user_name='my username (not shown for obvious reasons)'
password='my password (also not shown for obvious reasons)'
url_data='https://'+user_name+':'+password+'@opensky-network.org/api/states/all?'+'lamin='+str(lat_min)+'&lomin='+str(lon_min)+'&lamax='+str(lat_max)+'&lomax='+str(lon_max)


def flight_tracking(doc):
    flight_source = ColumnDataSource({
        'icao24':[],'callsign':[],'origin_country':[],
        'time_position':[],'last_contact':[],'long':[],'lat':[],
        'baro_altitude':[],'on_ground':[],'velocity':[],'true_track':[],
        'vertical_rate':[],'sensors':[],'geo_altitude':[],'squawk':[],'spi':[],'position_source':[],'x':[],'y':[],
        'rot_angle':[],'url':[]
    })
    
    def update():
        response=requests.get(url_data).json()
        
        col_name=['icao24','callsign','origin_country','time_position','last_contact','long','lat','baro_altitude','on_ground','velocity',       
'true_track','vertical_rate','sensors','geo_altitude','squawk','spi','position_source']
        flight_data=response['states']
        flight_df=pd.DataFrame(flight_data,columns=col_name)
        wgs84_to_web_mercator(flight_df)
        flight_df=flight_df.fillna('No Data')
        flight_df['rot_angle']=flight_df['true_track']*-1
        icon_url='https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/4c/4c507d3961382eefd8a48f5c387a0ee3.png' #icon url
        flight_df['url']=icon_url
        
        n_roll=len(flight_df.index)
        flight_source.stream(flight_df.to_dict(orient='list'),n_roll)
        
    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 5000)
    p=figure(x_range=x_range,y_range=y_range,x_axis_type='mercator',y_axis_type='mercator',sizing_mode='scale_width',plot_height=300)
    tile_prov=get_provider(STAMEN_TERRAIN)
    p.add_tile(tile_prov,level='image')
    p.image_url(url='url', x='x', y='y',source=flight_source,anchor='center',angle_units='deg',angle='rot_angle',h_units='screen',w_units='screen',w=40,h=40)
    p.circle('x','y',source=flight_source,fill_color='red',hover_color='yellow',size=10,fill_alpha=0.8,line_width=0)

    my_hover=HoverTool()
    my_hover.tooltips=[('Call sign','@callsign'),('Origin Country','@origin_country'),('velocity(m/s)','@velocity'),('Altitude(m)','@baro_altitude')]
    labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='callsign', level='glyph',
            x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=flight_source, render_mode='canvas',background_fill_color='white',text_font_size="8pt")
    p.add_tools(my_hover)
    p.add_layout(labels)
    
    doc.title='REAL TIME FLIGHT TRACKING'
    doc.add_root(p)
    
apps = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(flight_tracking))}
server = Server(apps, port=8084) #define an unused port
server.start()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/server/server.html#bokeh.server.server.BaseServer.start), all calling `start` does is install and enable Bokeh's machinery on an IOLoop.

> Install the Bokeh Server and its background tasks on a Tornado IOLoop.
>
> This method does not block and does not affect the state of the Tornado IOLoop You must start and stop the loop yourself, i.e. this method is typically useful when you are already explicitly managing an IOLoop yourself.
>
> To start a Bokeh server and immediately “run forever” in a blocking manner, see `run_until_shutdown()`.

You need to ster Tornado's `IOLoop` yourself (or call `run_until_shutdown`).

Note that neither of these options has anything to do with opening a browser window, if that is your expectation. Most of the time that's not what is desired, so if that is what you want you would need to add a callback to perform that action:

```py
from bokeh.util.browser import view
io_loop.add_callback(view, "http://localhost:5006/")
```

Comment: Is this replacing the server.start or not?

Comment: You can call `server.start()` and also manage the`IOLoop` yourself, or instead of those actions, you can call `run_until_shutdown()` which will make sure an `IOLoop` is running (note: this is a blocking call). There are several complete examples that show how to use `server.start` inthe example directory of the source repo.